# elemIndices in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wrote the code to get the element index

```
elemIndex :: [String] -> [String] -> [Int]
elemIndex [] [] = []
elemIndex x y = elemIndex True [(elem a y) | a <- x ]
```

is there any alternative way/similer of performing the above logic?

and also i've seen that some use

```
index [] _ = []
```

to return null lists

could you pls explain the use of underscore?

//edit 1
it is suposed to return the index of the values in the list.

eg: elemIndex ["asde","zxc","qwe"] ["qwe","zxc"]

returns [1,2] as the answer

thanks

Comment: elemIndex doesn't pass the typechecker... you are using a Bool when elemIndex expects a list of strings. What is elemIndex supposed to do?

Comment: it is suposed to return the index of the values in the list.
eg:

elemIndex ["asde","zxc","qwe"] ["qwe","zxc"]

returns [1,2] as the answer

Comment: Are the searched elements required to be in the same order as in the source list?

Comment: well i jus want to get the index of the items present. the list ["asde","zxc","qwe"] is fixed, if the element is present in this list i want the index to be as output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`elemIndex` takes two arguments (two lists). Right now you recursively call it with an additional argument of type bool (namely `True`). That will not work. What you probably want to do, is create a helper function, as I [showed you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872631/syntax-in-expression-haskell) an hour ago.

The `_`, as used as a formal argument, matches any input. It does not have a name, and as such, you cannot use that which is matched.

Aside from that, you probably don't want to use booleans, but integers (to keep track of a counter). The `elem` function only tells you *whether* some value is part of a list, not *where* it is. So, it is of little use to you. Since this appears to be homework I will not provide a solution to your problem, but perhaps you should split your code in two:

```
indices :: (Eq t) => [t] -> [t] -> [Integer]
getIndex :: (Eq t) => [t] -> t -> Integer
```

(`getIndex` may use a helper function `getIndex' :: (Eq t) => [t] -> t -> Integer -> Integer`.)

---

**Edit**: One possible solution (which uses a hack, it's nicer to use the `Maybe` monad):

```
indices :: (Eq t) => [t] -> [t] -> [Integer]
indices xs ys = filter (>= 0) $ map (getIndex xs) ys

getIndex :: (Eq t) => [t] -> t -> Integer
getIndex xs y = getIndex' xs y 0
  where
    getIndex' :: (Eq t) => [t] -> t -> Integer -> Integer
    getIndex' [] _ _                 = -1
    getIndex' (x:xs) y i | x == y    = i
                         | otherwise = getIndex' xs y (i + 1)
```

A version with the `Maybe` monad:

```
import Data.Maybe

indices :: (Eq t) => [t] -> [t] -> [Integer]
indices xs ys = mapMaybe (getIndex xs) ys

getIndex :: (Eq t) => [t] -> t -> Maybe Integer
getIndex xs y = getIndex' xs y 0
  where
    getIndex' :: (Eq t) => [t] -> t -> Integer -> Maybe Integer
    getIndex' [] _ _                 = Nothing
    getIndex' (x:xs) y i | x == y    = Just i
                         | otherwise = getIndex' xs y (i + 1)
```

And a version that leaves all heavy lifting to the standard library:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

indices :: (Eq t) => [t] -> [t] -> [Int]
indices xs ys = mapMaybe (`elemIndex` xs) ys
```

Comment: thanks, the code i've used gives me the desired output. but i jus want to find out a different of tackling the issue.

Comment: Good to hear you have a solution. I updated my answer to include the solution I hinted at.

Comment: im confused a bit
ys=["as","sas"]
zip [1..] ys 
woudl give
[(1,"as"),(2,"sas")] 

as ive mentioned earlier, 
elemIndex ["asde","zxc","qwe"] ["qwe","zxc"] 
would yield [2,1] since index of "qwe" is 2 and "zxc" is 1

so in this case zip function is helpful? or have i incorrectly used it?

thanks

Comment: Ah, in your question you stated that it should be [1,2] instead of [2,1]. When i read that, I assumed you wanted the indices in the second list, 1-indexed. So my initial hunch *was* correct. I'll add another solution in a minute.

Comment: ...done (and removed the code based on my incorrect assumption; you can still find it in the edit history).

Answer (score 2):

```
index [] _ = []
```

is the same as

```
index [] x = []
```

except you cannot use the `_` on the right hand side of the equals sign.

I don't understand what you want `elemIndex` to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement your function this way:

```
elemIndices acc n []  _ = acc
elemIndices acc n  _ [] = acc
elemIndices acc n (x:x') (y:y') = if x == y then 
                                      elemIndices (n:acc) (n+1) x' y'
                                  else
                                      elemIndices acc (n+1) x' (y:y')

elemIndex x y = reverse $ elemIndices [] 1 x y
```

When the elements in your source list are in the same order as the elements you look for, this is much more efficient (no use of `elem` - tail recursion). Ex:

```
elemIndex [3..7] [4, 6] -- Yields [2, 4]
```

Comment: Ah - I got you wrong. You want to have the indices in the first list. Sorry